# Our Thomson modem/routertg585v7 is struggling with the amount of gadgets in the house

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, modem

Our Thomson modem/router tg585v7 is struggling with the amount of gadgets in the house that need to go on the internet, 13 gadgets in all. As you can guess the modem/router locks up quite a lot. So, today I purchased what I thought was a modem/wireless router a Asus RT-N66U but its just a wireless router.

I need help to be able to connect through this

1. My PC running Windows XP (hard wired in to the Thomson modem/router)
2. The wife's iMac, also hard wired
3. A Sky Box, hard wired
4. Various other gadgets over wireless (iphones,xbox, ipad, fire kindle).

Quick count 13 in all ...Blimey!!!

Is this possible or should I replace my Thomson modem/router with another that anyone can recommend?

Comment: It should be able to handle that many connections. What do you mean when you say it locks up? For best performance, make sure that the firmware is up to date and the router has good ventilation to prevent overheating (they can sometimes get quite hot). You could try getting a refund for the Asus router if you were given bad advice by sales staff. Alternatively it should be possible to use your Thomson router as a modem and connect it to the Asus one - it could solve your problems but it may not be that straightforward to do.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the Thomson modem router has 802.11b/g wireless and integrated 10/100Mb/s 4- port switch with integrated ADSL modem. The ASUS router you purchased is a great router and significantly better than the Thomson for routing. It has dual-band wireless N support and a 4-port gigabit switch. Here are some references:

- [Coding horror mention](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/06/because-everyone-still-needs-a-router.html)
- [SmallNetBuilder review](http://www.smallnetbuilder.com/wireless/wireless-reviews/31687-asus-rt-n66u-dark-knight-dual-band-wireless-n900-gigabit-router-reviewed)

I would definitely recommend making that the primary router for all of your systems and just use the Thomson device as a modem.